# Woocommerce variation subscription not showing in Basket when adding product using shortcode

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

My web site requires that I use an add-to-cart shortcode to add my products to the basket, however when I do so it doesn't show the details of the variation in my basket

Originally I was just using...

https://evolvefitness.co.uk/checkout/?add-to-cart=9327

...to add the variation but I thought I may need to be more specific so changed it to the below link...

https://evolvefitness.co.uk/checkout/?add-to-cart=9275&variation_id=9327

Unfortunately I still don't get the variation description that I do when I go into the product itself and make the selection process normally.

It's strange because it is selecting the correct product variation and you can see that when you hover over the links in the Cart, it just doesn't seem to want to display.

[image: Screenshot showing 1 item added through the product page with full description and others added with the link]

Do I need to add some more detail to the add-to-cart link that I'm missing?

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To give you the following answer, I first tried to monitor the outgoing traffic in both cases, both when the request to add to the cart is made directly, and when you do it through the link you provided. Here's what I found and what you could do:

While your requests are GETs to which you pass parameters, what is done directly is a POST with more parameters in the query. Here is a direct example

```
// Your GET request
https://evolvefitness.co.uk/checkout/?add-to-cart=9275&variation_id=9327
```

where the parameters are the add-to-cart and variation_id

```
// The direct POST request
https://evolvefitness.co.uk/shop/warrior-tribe-transformation/?attribute_duration=8+week+programme&attribute_location=Evolve+Blackfriars&attribute_time=08%3A10
```

and the parameters are the following

```
attribute_duration: 12 week programme
attribute_location: Evolve Blackfriars
attribute_time: 08:10
quantity: 1
add-to-cart: 9275
product_id: 9275
variation_id: 9310
```

Therefore, after some trial and error I found the correct link you want to have to make the correct GET, of course choosing your parameters values

```
// Solution GET
https://evolvefitness.co.uk/checkout/?add-to-cart=9275&attribute_duration=12+week+programme&attribute_location=Evolve+Blackfriars&attribute_time=08%3A10
```